# Which of the following admit a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which of the following two-point boundary value problems admit a
unique solution?

$1$$. −u''(x) = 2x$ in $0 < x < 1 $ and $u(0) = u(1) = 0$

$2$$. −u''(x) = 2x$ in $0 < x < 1 $ and $u(0) = u'(1) = 0$

$3$$. −u''(x) = 2x$ in $0 < x < 1 $ and $u'(0) = u'(1) = 0$

$4.$ None of these

**My attempt** :$ u''=-2x \implies  r^2=-2$

so  $r=  \pm \sqrt2i$

Hence  $u(x)= c_1 \cos (\sqrt2x) + c_2 \sin (\sqrt2x)\tag1$

if $u(0)=0$

then $u(0)=c_1=0 $

If $u(1) =0$ ,then put $c_1 =0 $ in $(1)$, then we get $c_2=0$

Here we can not uniquely determine $c_2$ , so  there are infinitely many solution

Similarly we can use the same method for option  $2)$ and $3)$

So  i think that answer will be none of these i,e option $4$ will be correct

Comment: You are considering $u''+2u=0$ instead of $u''=-2x$. So, you may check again what differential equation is given.

Comment: There is a typo in there somewhere, either the actual question is $u'' = -2u$ or the calculations are completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u''=-2x.$ Integrate w.r. x to get
$u'=-x^2+A$ again integrate to get
$$u(x)=-x^3/3+Ax+B~~~(1)$$ $u(0)=0$ gives $B=0$, then $u(1)=0$ gives $0=-1/3+A \implies A=1/3$. So we get the unique solution as $u(x)=-x^3/3+1/3$

Next. from (1) $u(0)=0 \implies B=0$ and $u'(1)=0$ gives u'(x)=-x^2+A \implies $A=2$, so the solution is  $u(x)=2x-x^2$

$u'(0)=0$ gives $A=0$ then $u'(x)=-x^2$, where $u'(1) \ne 0$. So no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Both 1 and 2 are the right answers:

U"=-2x,  U'=$-x^2+C$,  U=-$\frac{x^3}{3}+Cx+D$

1: U(0)=U(1)=0, D=0, C=$\frac{1}{3}$, $\to$ U= -$\frac{x^3}{3}$+$\frac{1}{3}$x

2. U(0)=U'(1)= 0,  D=0,C=1  $\to$ U= -$\frac{x^3}{3}$+x